# Forecast the turnover with a prophet model in R

Tags: beginner, r

I am a student who is interested in data analytics and currently figuring out how to write forecast models for several scenarios in R. I'm working on a fictitious project in which I want to forecast the turnover for all months of 2023 by having historical data since 2010, which are affected by the Inflation Rate and the mean shopping card.

I have a working R script and I hope to to receive some suggestions/reviews on how to improve the code or the model.

```
#load packages
library(readxl)
library(prophet)
library(ggplot2)

# define path
excel_file_path <- "/Users/XYZ/Desktop/Data/DataToForecast.xlsx"

# Daten aus der Excel-Datei importieren
data <- read_excel(excel_file_path)

# prepare data
data <- data[, c("Year", "Month", "Turnover", "InflationRate", "MeanShoppingCard")]
colnames(data) <- c("ds", "Month", "y", "InflationRate", "MeanShoppingCard")
data$ds <- as.Date(paste(data$ds, data$Month, "01", sep="-"))

# check data
str(data)
summary(data)

# generate new data frame for prophet
prophet_data <- data.frame(ds = data$ds, 
                           y = data$y, 
                           InflationRate = data$InflationRate, 
                           MeanShoppingCard = data$MeanShoppingCard)

#initiate model
prophet_model <- prophet()

# Adding exogenous regressors
prophet_model <- add_regressor(prophet_model, "InflationRate")
prophet_model <- add_regressor(prophet_model, "MeanShoppingCard")

# set hyperparameters
prophet_model <- prophet(prophet_data, 
                         changepoint.prior.scale = 0.04,
                         growth = "linear",
                         holidays = NULL,
                         yearly.seasonality = TRUE,
                         changepoints = NULL,
                         seasonality.mode = "additive",
                         holidays.prior.scale = 0.001,
                         mcmc.samples = 2000,
                         interval.width = 0.95)

# prediction
future <- make_future_dataframe(prophet_model, periods = 12, freq = "month")
future$InflationRate <- data$InflationRate[1]
future$MeanShoppingCard <- data$MeanShoppingCard[1]
forecast <- predict(prophet_model, future)

# plot
plot(prophet_model, forecast) +
  labs(title = "Forecast 2023",
       x = "Date",
       y = "Turnover")
```